# Triangle Inequality for norm integral $\|f\|_1=(\int_a^b [|f|^2+|f'|^2]\mathsf dx)^{1/2}$.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Define $C_1^1[a,b]$ to be the space of continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$, with norm $$\|f\|_1=\left(\int_a^b[|f|^2+|f'|^2]\mathsf dx\right)^{1/2}.$$ Show that this is a proper definition of a norm. Is this normed space complete?

I'm stuck on the triangle inequality part. I'm having a hard time showing that $$\|f+g\|_1\leq \|f\|_1+\|g\|_1.$$ Any hints or solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: yeah, but I can't figure out how to split this integral sum into two different integrals because everything s raised to ${1/2}$.

Comment: When I square both sides I end with the result wanted plus $2\int_a^b|f||g||f'||g'|dx$.

Comment: You mean $2\int |f||g|dx+2\int |f'||g'|dx$.

Comment: yes, sorry, how can those two integrals disappear for the result.

Comment: Now apply Cauchy-Schwartz.  $\int |f||g|dx\le \sqrt{\int |f|^2dx\int|g|^2dx}$.

Comment: Even after applying Cauchy-Schwartz I still has some terms that won't disappear. Don't we just want to end up with $\int_a^b|f|^2+|f'|^2 dx + \int_a^b |g|^2+|g'|^2 dx$?

Comment: The answer is perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: Wow!  Thank you.  That made my day.  And you're certainly welcome.  It was my pleasure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We will assume that $f$ and $g$ are real-valued.  The proof for complex-valued $f$ and $g$ follows analogously.

Let $||f||_1^2\equiv \int_a^b|f|^2dx+\int_a^b|f'|^2dx$.  Then, we have

$$\begin{align}
||f+g||_1^2&=\int_a^b|f+g|^2\,dx+\int_a^b|f'+g'|^2\,dx\\\\
&=\int_a^b(|f|^2+|f'|^2)\,dx+\int_a^b (|g|^2+|g'|^2)\,dx \\\\
&+2\int_a^b(fg+f'g')\,dx \tag 1\\\\
&\le \int_a^b(|f|^2+|f'|^2)\,dx+\int_a^b (|g|^2+|g'|^2)\,dx\\\\
&+2\sqrt{\int_a^b(|f|^2+|f'|^2)\,dx}\sqrt{\int_a^b(|g|^2+|g'|^2)dx} \tag 2\\\\
&=\left(\sqrt{\int_a^b(|f|^2+|f'|^2)\,dx}+\sqrt{\int_a^b(|g|^2+|g'|^2)\,dx}\right)^2\\\\
&=\left(||f||_1+||g||_1\right)^2
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!

---

**NOTE:**

In going from $(1)$ to $(2)$, we used the Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality.  To prove the inequality explicitly here, we first note that

$$\int_a^b\left(f-\frac{\int_a^b(fg+f'g')\,dx'}{\int_a^b(g^2+g'^2)\,dx'}\,g\right)^2\,dx+\int_a^b\left(f'-\frac{\int_a^b(fg+f'g')\,dx'}{\int_a^b(g^2+g'^2)\,dx'}\,g'\right)^2 \ge 0$$

since the integrands of both integrals are non-negative.  Then, completing the squares of both integrands and gathering terms yields

$$\left(\int_a^b(f^2+f'^2)\,dx\right)\left(\int_a^b(g^2+g'^2)\,dx\right)\ge \left(\int_a^b(fg+f'g')\,dx\right)^2 \tag 3$$

Taking the square root of both sides of $(3)$, we obtain the desired result

$$\int_a^b(fg+f'g')\,dx\le \sqrt{\left(\int_a^b(f^2+f'^2)\,dx\right)}\sqrt{\left(\int_a^b(g^2+g'^2)\,dx\right)}$$

Comment: Are there some hidden steps in your solution? I can't justify the going from the second to last line. Expanding the last but one line doesn't give the third line from the bottom. Also I thought $\|f\|_1 = \sqrt {\int_a^b( |f|^2 + |f'|^2)dx}  $ but it seems you are saying $\|f\|_1 = \sqrt {\int_a^b (|f|+|f'|)^2 dx}$. Am I missing something?

Comment: So what is it that am I not getting.

Comment: I understand almost everything. it is the last two lines that are giving me problems. I don't see why\ $$\int_a^b(|f|^2+|f'|^2)dx+2\sqrt{\int_a^b(|f|+|f'|)^2dx\int_a^b(|g|+|g'|)^2dx}+\int_a^b (|g|^2+|g'|^2)dx
=\left(\sqrt{\int_a^b(|f|+|f'|)^2dx}+\sqrt{\int_a^b(|g|+|g'|)^2dx}\right)^2
=\left(||f||_1+||g||_1\right)^2 $$

Comment: This is what I get. $$\left(\sqrt{\int_a^b(|f|+|f'|)^2dx}+\sqrt{\int_a^b(|g|+|g'|)^2dx}\right)^2 =  \\ \int_a^b (|f|+|f'|)^2 dx +  2 \sqrt{\int_a^b (|f|+|f'|)^2 dx \int_a^b(|g|+|g'|)^2 dx}  +\int_a^b (|g|+|g'|)^2  dx $$

Comment: @Gorg First, thank you for bringing this to my attention.  I posted this answer a while ago, around the time of the forth surgery I'd had over a 14 month period.  So, I am not sure how I had missed this.  I've edited and now the solution is sound.  +1 for you comments that prompted my editing this!

Comment: Thanks for not dismissing my comments. I appreciate you taking the trouble to edit the solution. You've been immense! +1

Comment: @Gorg Wow!  Thank you for the nice comment.  And it is I who thanks you for pointing out your valid concern!  I consider you a MSE friend - one of the good guys on the site.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** prove that this norm is induced by an inner product, it will be easier: $$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_a^b f(x)g(x) + f'(x)g'(x)\,{\rm d}x$$

Throw in some conjugates for the complex case. This is the only case that your norm comes from an inner product. In general, we have that $$\|f\|_p = \left( \int_a^b \sum_{j = 0}^k |f^{(j)}(x)|^p \,{\rm d}x \right)^{1/p}, $$ for $1\leq p < \infty$ is a norm in the space of the $C^k$ functions, but this one is harder to prove, you'll have to use some variant of Hölder's inequality, and such.

These spaces are not Banach spaces, as pointed in the comments.

Comment: The given space is not complete. The completion is the first Sobolev space, which consists of all absolutely continuous functions $f$ on $[a,b]$ for which $f' \in L^{2}$.